# Combined plot for hardware monitoring

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am monitoring CPU, RAM and disk IO for a computational pipeline that consists of multiple steps to process the input data. I would like to visualize the hardware consumption for the entire pipeline but also per step of the pipeline.

In order to render hardware consumptions, I'd like to draw a combined plot with jFreeChart with four vertically aligned subplots that all have the same x-axis - time. The top plot is supposed to be a gantt plot to indicate the step of the pipeline. In the second plot I'd like to render the CPU consumption over time. In the third plot the RAM consumption, the bottom plot is for disk IO. The aim is to visually slide horizontally over the plot and see, which step of the pipeline uses how much CPU, RAM and disk.

I'm all set up in eclipse, jFreeChart library installed and all my data is imported and ready to render. All I need is some guidance for how to set up the combined chart up, cause my code blows up, when I try to combine the Gantt plot (which is a category plot) and the CPU plot (which is XY plot):

```java
    public JFreeChart createChart() {

        final JFreeChart ganttChart = ChartFactory.createGanttChart(
                "Gantt of Tasks", // chart title
                "Task", // domain axis label
                "Time", // range axis label
                createGanttDataset(), // data
                true, // include legend
                true, // tooltips
                false // urls
        );

        JFreeChart cpuChart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
                "CPU load", // title
                "Time", // x-axis label
                "CPU Load", // y-axis label
                createCpuDataset(), // data
                true, // create legend?
                true, // generate tooltips?
                false // generate URLs?
        );

        // parent plot...
        final CombinedRangeCategoryPlot plot = new CombinedRangeCategoryPlot();
        plot.setGap(10.0);

        // add the subplots...
        plot.add(ganttChart.getCategoryPlot(), 1);
        plot.add(cpuChart.getCategoryPlot(), 1);
        plot.setOrientation(PlotOrientation.VERTICAL);

        // return a new chart containing the overlaid plot...
        return new JFreeChart("Combined GANTT/CPU plot",
                JFreeChart.DEFAULT_TITLE_FONT, plot, true);

    }

    private IntervalCategoryDataset createGanttDataset() {
        final TaskSeries taskSeries = new TaskSeries("Tasks");
        for (Map.Entry<DoubleLong, String> entry : algoStartEndDates.entrySet()) {
            final String taskTitle = entry.getValue();
            final long startDate = entry.getKey().n1;
            final long endDate = entry.getKey().n2;
            taskSeries.add(new Task(taskTitle, new SimpleTimePeriod(startDate, endDate)));
        }
        final TaskSeriesCollection collection = new TaskSeriesCollection();
        collection.add(taskSeries);
        return collection;
    }

    private XYDataset createCpuDataset() {
        final TimeSeries timeSeries = new TimeSeries("CPU load");
        for (CollectlData data : collectlData) {
            final RegularTimePeriod t = new Millisecond(new Date(data.getUtcTime()));
            timeSeries.add(t, data.getCpuData().getTotal());
        }
        final TimeSeriesCollection dataset = new TimeSeriesCollection();
        dataset.addSeries(timeSeries);
        dataset.setDomainIsPointsInTime(true);
        return dataset;
    }
```

I would expect this to create a combined plot, but I'm receiving the error message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot cannot be cast to class org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot (org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot and org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart.getCategoryPlot(JFreeChart.java:824) ~[jfreechart-1.0.15.jar:1.0.15]
```

Comment: `JFreeChart::getCategoryPlot`: "NOTE: if the plot is not an instance of `CategoryPlot`, then a `ClassCastException` is thrown."

Comment: Thats right ... and I understand the ClassCastException. The provided code was to indicate, what Im trying to do. The question remains, what the right way is to combine these plots in one chart.

Comment: AFAIK, combining a category and _xy_ plot is not supported; you might look at a `ChartMouseListener` on the Gantt plot that updates a marker on the combined plot.